# How to get quickly size and location of all elements on the webpages by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get size and location of each element on the webpage.
If I try naive approach then it is very slow (typically, it takes approx. 2 minutes to process some common pages like www.amazon.com etc.).

Is there some significantly faster way how to get these information?

My naive approach:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(..."\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
for e in html.find_elements_by_css_selector("*"):
    size = e.size
    location = e.location
```

Comment: try to use "headless" Chrome

Comment: Why do you need all of this? Most of the elements on the page are likely to not be visible thus have no position and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are hoping to do with this information, but use javascript executors to run the following Javascript. If you need the data in a different format, feel free to edit it however you want your script to consume it. This will take about 1 second to get all of this information.

```js
var returnValues = "";
var els = $("*:visible");
for(var x = 0; x < els.length; x++) {
  
  returnValues += `${$(els[x]).height()},${$(els[x]).width()},${$(els[x]).position().left},${$(els[x]).position().top}|`;
  console.log(`${$(els[x]).height()} x ${$(els[x]).width()}`);
  console.log(`pos: x:${$(els[x]).position().left} y:${$(els[x]).position().top}`);

}
return returnValues;
```

This can be launched via `var results = driver.execute_script("Above javascript").split("|");`

Comment: Great, it works really nicely. It is part of my research project on webpage classifications - so I hope that it helps me to classify type of webpages. 
Thank you very much for your help. It improved performance of my application really significantly.